# configure curl to get www.google.com

Tags: php, curl

How to get curl response properly using php curl. I tried to change some request header and user agent

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

but its not working am getting 302 error

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.in/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=30a99703e541807e:FF=0:TM=1324467004:LM=1324467004:S=0VlXyYEJtxKQ_Pqk; expires=Fri, 20-Dec-2013 11:30:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 11:30:04 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 221
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

the html output that i get is

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

how to get and post data using php curl as if we are doing it from browser.

here is my php code for `curl_setopt`

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
```

Comment: 302 is not an error, the code superior to 400 are errors!

Comment: What's your question? The response from Google is redirecting you to their India site - is that not what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.in/
```

tells you to go to http://www.google.co.in/ for the content, so you have to do another cURL sequence there.

Comment: -1 follow location will allow you to do this in one curl operation

Answer (score 5):

Set the cURL `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option to `true`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Will will instruct cURL to follow any "Location: " headers that the server sends. More info available in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).